# External CD Drive as a substitute to the Apple Superdrive

Tags: usb, osx, dvd-player

Many MacBooks don't have an internal CD drive, notably the Air, and as a result, people who have CDs are forced to get an external drive. I love music, and I've got tons of it on CDs, so I want a drive.

But [the drive that Apple sells](http://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MD564LL/A/apple-usb-superdrive) is ridiculously expensive, coming up at $99. There's mixed reviews about it as well.

I'm looking for a USB 2.0 external CD drive with decent read/write capabilities. It needs to be compatible with OS X and ideally with Windows as well. It should be fairly fast, and look decent as well.

I'm willing to spend up to $20 on this. I'm flexible on this, but I don't want to spend a lot of money on something that previous came "standard" on laptops.

Comment: Are you a fan of auto-opening and closing or manual?

Comment: @Adam Doesn't really matter. As long as it works :)

Comment: Any drive that follows the USB mass storage standard (ie. most of them) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of external USB CD drives within the price range:

- [2017 2016 Ultra Thin External USB 2.0 CD ROM CD Driver CD/DVD Optical Driver Portable CD Driver For PC Laptop-in Optical Drives from Computer & Office on Aliexpress.com | Alibaba Group](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2016-Ultra-Thin-External-USB-2-0-CD-ROM-CD-Driver-CD-DVD-Optical-Driver-Portable/32653762903.html)
- [LG Super Multi Portable DVD Rewriter with M-Disc 328005 - Micro Center (UPC: 058231309133)](http://www.microcenter.com/product/485814/Super_Multi_Portable_DVD_Rewriter_with_M-Disc)